# JPA annotation replace characters on insert

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have an Entity where I declare a field called "name". This field represents a file name. What I need to do is to replace all special characters that aren't allowed on Windows file names with empty or another string, so that they don't go to the DB when I save that entity.

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Where(clause = "is_active = true")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "File")
public class FileEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "Name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

So let's say I place a name `School project : 123` I want to replace the colons with underline, just like you would do via `name.replaceAll("[^/./\\:*?\"<>|]", "_");`, thus the resulting name stored in the DB would be `School project _ 123`

Is this even possible through an annotation (to include that `replaceAll()` there) or am I asking the wrong question here?

Comment: You forgot to match one or more occurrences, `"[^/.\\\\:*?\"<>|]+"` (and if you wanted to add a backslash, it should be ``\\\\`` in the string literal)

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually supported out-of-the-box. You probably could add some annotation handling mechanism but I'm not sure this would be worth the effort. You could use validation to reject those values or you could implement a setter that alters the value if needed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, the setter seems to be the way to go. I kind of overthought this and completely disregarded the use of getters and setters. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare setter in which convert original string by replacing symbols you want to replace.

Comment: How could I not think of this? (Probably because I use Lombok) It's literally too simple :)

Thanks for the suggestion.